# How to pull a post object based on the current post being referanced in it?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I have set up a custom post type for product videos called 'tv', and I've added a custom field to that which calls products as post objects.

I'd now like to reverse engineer that so that if products are referenced in that field, a link appears to the correct video on the product page. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

    $thisinstrument = get_post($post->ID,$output = OBJECT,$filter = 'raw');
    
    $posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'tv',
    'meta_key'      => 'instruments',
    'meta_value'    =>  $thisinstrument
    
    ));

    if( $posts ): ?>
    
    <!-- TV -->
    
    <ul>
        
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        
        setup_postdata( $post );
        
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
    
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    
    </ul>
    
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

I think i'm on the right lines. At first I set $thisinstrument to get_post($post = 'null',$output = OBJECT,$filter = 'raw'); and that just printed all posts.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that "'meta_key' => 'instruments'", should contain the ID of the current post so when you queried the $thisinstrument, you should have used $post->ID.
I believe the following code should help you get this done.

```
<?php
    
    // $thisinstrument =.... No need for this line if the 'instruments' field is the ID of the current post, we can just insert that inside the get_posts() below.

  GLOBAL $post;
  $posts = get_posts(array(

    'numberposts'   => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'tv',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'instruments',
            'value' => $post->ID,
        )
    )
));

if( $posts ): ?>

<!-- TV -->

<ul>
    
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
    
    setup_postdata( $post );
    
    ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php the_title($post->ID); ?></a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I believe this should do it, give it a try and let me know I might have read you wrong.

Comment: Ok I just tested it with no luck (sorry for the delay) - Any Ideas? You are correct that meta key is the ID of the custom field that needs to match the 'current' post ID in the loop.

Comment: #Coopero I have updated the code, please try it again.

Comment: Thanks - but no luck, I had to remove ```array(``` because it was causing an error written twice, now it prints all posts of the tv type. When I change post amount to 1 it just prints the single most recent. Thanks for your help - what do you think?

Comment: I updated the code again. The code should get you what you want unless you have an issue. May I ask if you can contact me at my email? its a bit shallow to discuss this issue, there are some grey areas here. check my profile.